# Determining the importance of items across sets?

Tags: pattern-matching

There's a better term for it. Let's say i have a suite of sets - A, B, C, D.

Each set contains any number, in a non-important order, of items - 1,2,3,4,5,6 The items may occur any number (0 or more) of times in a set.

Is there some agreed-upon formula to determine the "most important" item? Or are there algorithms for this?

Comment: The question makes no sense unless you tell us your definition of "most important".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich oh! good one! I don't know, i was honestly hoping there would be an algorithm for that. i'm settling for tf-idf, but is there anything else to consider?

Comment: "an  algorithm for that: an algorithm for _what_?

Comment: Yes this is known as poset , partially pre-ordered set